# Alert not show after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input required="required" name="query" type="text" class="form-control indexInputSzukaj" id="inputValidation" placeholder="Znajdź" value="">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback glyphiconColor showActionAfterClick"></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.showActionAfterClick').click(function() {
        alert('ok');
    });
});
```

This code was created in bootstrap.

I need to show alert box after click `showActionAfterClick` class, but it's not working.

How can I repair it?

Comment: $('.showActionAfterClick') you should not have space between . and class name

Comment: mind the space in class name specifier it should be `.showActionAfterClick`

Comment: it's not help :(

Comment: You have a space between your selector and the classname `$('. showActionAfterClick')` moreover you do not have anything inside span so, you may not know whether you are actually `click`ing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a space between your class identifier (`.`) and your classname `showActionAfterClick`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.showActionAfterClick').click(function() {
    alert('ok');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<div class="form-group ">
  <div class="form-group has-feedback ">
    <input required="required" name="query" type="text" class="form-control indexInputSzukaj" id="inputValidation" placeholder="Znajdź" value="">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback glyphiconColor showActionAfterClick">Text to see this button</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, this happend because the span is an inline element and its width size depends of its content. So the span element have not width and you can't click it and trigger the alert (besides the bad syntax in your jquery query selector).
The @Jack Bashford example works because the span element has text inside and this provides the width to that element.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="form-group ">
<div class="form-group has-feedback ">
<input required="required" name="query" type="text" class="form-control indexInputSzukaj" id="inputValidation" placeholder="Znajdź" value="">
<span id ="showActionAfterClick" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback glyphiconColor">Click ME!</span>
</div>
</div>



$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#showActionAfterClick').click(function() {
            alert('ok');
        });
});
```

add id in your span tag instead of class and replace . with # and try now

Answer (score -1):

Use this

```
<div class="form-group ">
<div class="form-group has-feedback ">
<input required="required" name="query" type="text" class="form-control indexInputSzukaj" id="inputValidation" placeholder="Znajdź" value="">
<span onclick="test()" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search form-control-feedback glyphiconColor"></span>
</div>
</div>


<script>
function test(){
alert("ok");
}
</script>
```